# Endofunctors of $\textsf{FinVec}$ which are not $C^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds

Let $\textsf{FinVec}$ denote the category of finite-dimensional real vector spaces. For each vector space $V \in \textsf{FinVec}$, choose a vector space isomorphism $\varphi \colon V \to \mathbb{R}^{\dim V}$ and endow $V$ with the standard smooth structure from $\mathbb{R}^{\dim V}$ pulled back along $\varphi$. I think (correct me if I'm wrong!) that this smooth structure on $V$ is independent of the choice of $\varphi$ up to diffeomorphism.

---

**Definition** Let $n \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ (where we use the convention that $\mathbb{N}$ includes $0$). A functor $F \colon \textsf{FinVec} \to \textsf{FinVec}$ is called $C^n$ iff
$$f \mapsto F(f) \colon \operatorname{Hom}(V,W) \to \operatorname{Hom}(F(V), F(W))$$
is a $C^n$ function for all $V,W \in \textsf{FinVec}$ (where the smooth structures on the hom sets are the ones described above, as these hom sets are finite dimensional real vector spaces under pointwise addition & scalar multiplication).

---

Of course, any $C^n$ functor is also $C^m$ whenever $m \leq n$, and in particular $C^\infty$ functors are $C^n$ for all $n$. Examples of $C^\infty$ functors include:

- $\operatorname{Hom}(V,{-})$ for any $V \in \textsf{FinVec}$
- $V \otimes {-}$ for any $V \in \textsf{FinVec}$
- The exterior algebra functor

However, I've been unable to think of any examples of an endofunctor of $\textsf{FinVec}$ which is not $C^\infty$! So:

**Does there exist an endofunctor of $\textsf{FinVec}$ which is not $C^\infty$?**

If the answer is yes, then my follow-up questions are:

**Does there exist an endofunctor of $\textsf{FinVec}$ which is not $C^0$? If $n,m \in \mathbb{N} \cup \{\infty\}$ with $m < n$, does there exist an endofunctor of $\textsf{FinVec}$ which is $C^m$ but not $C^n$?**

Comment: I think every continuous endofunctor is $C^{\infty}$; this should be a variation on the proof that continuous homomorphism of Lie groups is $C^{\infty}$. I'm not sure if there are discontinuous endofunctors. There are over $\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: Likewise, I cannot think of any discontinuos endos.

Comment: To clarify, over $\mathbb{C}$ there are "wild" endofunctors coming from composing scalar multiplication with discontinuous endomorphisms $\mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$, of which there are many (because $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed). But $\mathbb{R}$ has no nontrivial endomorphisms as a ring. All the endofunctors I know over $\mathbb{R}$ are direct sums of Schur functors, which are $C^{\infty}$ and even algebraic: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_functor

Comment: @QiaochuYuan To check my understanding: take a discontinuous ring automorphism $\alpha$ of $\mathbb{C}$. For each $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $V$, fix a basis and let $\overline{\alpha}_V : V \to V$ be the function $(x_1,\dots,x_n) \mapsto (\alpha(x_1),\dots,\alpha(x_n))$. Now we can construct an endofunctor $F$ of $\textsf{FinVec}_\mathbb{C}$ by sending each object to itself and a linear map $f : V \to W$ to $\overline{\alpha}_W \circ f \circ \overline{\alpha}_V^{-1}$. This functor is not $C^0$ because (e.g.) the map on $\text{Hom}(\mathbb{C},\mathbb{C})$ is canonically diffeo. to $\alpha$.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: it's unnecessary to fix a basis, and not quite. A vector space over $\mathbb{C}$ is an abelian group $A$ together with an action $\rho : \mathbb{C} \to \text{End}(A)$. If $\alpha : \mathbb{C} \to \mathbb{C}$ is an endomorphism, then given an action $\rho$ you can produce a new action $\rho \circ \alpha$; this is the functor. Note that this construction doesn't require $\alpha$ to be invertible.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm familiar with the idea of constructing a functor $f^* : R-\textsf{Mod} \to S-\textsf{Mod}$ from a ring homomorphism $f : S \to R$. However, doesn't this functor send a linear map to itself (the same function of underlying sets)? If so, won't it give the identity function $\text{Hom}(V,W) \to \text{Hom}(V,W)$ (which is necessarily continuous)?

Comment: Well, you have to pay attention to what you mean by "continuous". Do all your rings and modules have topologies on them? In the case of real  or complex vector spaces, every f.d. vector space has a unique Hausdorff topology on it that makes it into a topological vector space. Since the different vector space structures induce different topologies on the same set, the corresponding hom-sets will carry different topologies as well, so the identity function is not continuous.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk: $\alpha$ changes the topology and smooth structure we're considering on $A$.

Comment: Ooh, here's an endofunctor for the real case: compose any one of @QiaochuYuan 's wild endofunctors with the complexification functor (and then promptly forget the complex structure, of course)